# type() not working with input() and always returns "str" - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python `type()` always returns `str` even if I input an `int` or `float`.

I want to return length only if the input value is a valid string. The code that I've written always returns length regardless of the input being string or int.

I am using **python3**.

**Suspect:** `input()`. As it always returns string. But, is there any way I can get my code running with `input()` and `type()`?

```
Approach 1:

    def calc_length(s):
        if type(s) == int:
            print("Only Strings Have Lengths!!! Please enter a string!!")
        elif type(s) == float:
            print("Only Strings Have Lengths!!! Please enter a string!!")
        else:
            print(len(s))

    calc_length(input("Please enter a String: "))


---------------------------------------------------------------------
Approach 2:

    def calc_length(s):
        if type(s) != str:
            print("Only Strings Have Lengths!!! Please enter a string!!")
        else:
            print(len(s))

    calc_length(input("Please enter a String: "))
```

**Output:**
[image: output_screenshot_int_float_string]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It's suggested that you read the docs first, and check the return type of `input()`.

Comment: Thanks @fikr4n for the suggestion. I went through the docs and that's where I stuck when I tried evaluating the digits using input()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function input() always returns string. If you want to check if input is integer and/or float you can try casting it to int/float using `int(input("Please enter a String: "))`  or `float(input("Please enter a String: "))` and checking for `ValueError` exception. If user does not enter integer/float int()/float() throws exception.

```
user_input = input ("Enter  a string: ")
try:
   val = float(user_input) 
   print("Only Strings Have Lengths!!! Please enter a string!!")
except ValueError:
   print(len(user_input))
```

You can also use `isdigit()` method to check if input is integer. Note that this method assumes float to be string and display its length as float has '.' character which is non-numeric.

```
user_input = input ("Enter  a string: ")
if (user_input.isdigit()):
    print("Only Strings Have Lengths!!! Please enter a string!!")
else:
    print(len(user_input))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, `input()` returns a `string`. I found another [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4599hl/module_to_guess_type_from_a_string/) somewhere which suggested eg.,

```
import ast

type(ast.literal_eval("5"))
>> <class 'int'>
```

You could adapt this for your code. But I find it pretty objectionable! The user should be giving some specific type of input, and you should deal with parsing that type or else throw an error.

Comment: Thanks @ATayler ! Your solution helps for identifying Digits. But, for ast evaluation, we need to forcefully enter the input string in quotes. Else, it will fail to evaluate the input.

Comment: @GiteshShroti The whole point of your original question was to "guess" a type for some string that you received as input, eg. `type(ast.literal_eval(input()))`, if you're writing source code directly (ie. without quotes) then there's no need to manually guess the type because the interpreter is doing that for you..

Comment: Again, this evaluation is driven from "User End".

Answering your question for expecting _user to give specific type of input_, I prefer developing, even the simplest, code considering least understanding burden on user end.

But yes. Your efforts answering my query are really appreciated. Thanks for the valuable solution!

Comment: That's what I wanted. I wanted to evaluate the input without specifying any specific type(eg. without quoted string).

Comment: @GiteshShroti then just use `ast_literal_eval(input())` (or see the link I put above which shows how to default to string if guessing fails so the user would need to enter just eg. `hello` rather than `"hello"`)